# How to remove % symbol for particular column in dataframeusing python pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

My data frame have following data:

```
company,standard,returns
aaa,b1,10%
bbb,b2,20%
```

I have to remove `%` from `returns` column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First remove last value of each string by [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) and then cast to `int` or `float`:

```
#if int values
print (df['returns'].str[:-1].astype(int))

#if flaot values
print (df['returns'].str[:-1].astype(float))
```

Sample:

```
print (df)
  company standard returns
0    tata       b1     10%
1    dell       b2     10%

#if int values
df['returns'] = (df['returns'].str[:-1].astype(int))
print (df)
  company standard  returns
0    tata       b1       10
1    dell       b2       10
```

Another solution with [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['returns'] = (df['returns'].str.strip('%').astype(int))
print (df)
  company standard  returns
0    tata       b1       10
1    dell       b2       10
```

Answer (score 1):

Use vectorized [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace):

```
In [225]:
df['returns'] = df['returns'].str.replace('\%','')
df

Out[225]:
  company standard returns
0     aaa       b1      10
1     bbb       b2      20
```

You can cast the `dtype` afterwards using `astype(int)` or `astype(float)`